# Writing RFID User Memory in ZPL with nice bit field referencing like ^RB provides

Tags: rfid, plc, zpl

We're using a Toshiba B-EX4T1 printer, in ZPL emulation mode.  And am successfully printing tags with EPC RFID coding for SGTIN-96.
This is occurring directly from a PLC (at one site a Rockwell ControlLogix, at another a Siemens S7-1500.. just waiting for someone to use a Schneider M580 so I can 'collect them all').

For the EPC writing, I'm using `^RB96,...^RFW,E,...,E^FD....^FS` to get the right values into the right bit offsets etc.

What I'm now trying to do is write some additional GS-1 AI data to the User Memory field (AI10 Batch, AI30 Count, AI3100 Mass kg).  I've worked my way through the TDS specification (https://www.gs1.org/standards/tds), so I know which bits I want to go where...  but it seems that from my attempts at using `^RB136,...` and then `^RFW,E,...,3^FD^FS` this is not an option (it doesn't write anything into the User Memory field).

I've re-written my logic to jam all the bits and offsets together so that I can write it all as a hex string, using the `^RFW,H,...^FD^FS` syntax... but it's looking a bit ugly, and it would be much nicer if `^RB` could be used.

Does anyone know if `^RB` does work for this (and I'm possibly doing something else wrong), or if there is another way to allow for a more declarative bit field referencing (like ^RB provides) whilst addressing the User Memory.